# dependency conflicts while schema validation?

Tags: java, jboss

I updated the schema from RAML to OAS3 in my code

After updating and hitting the URL from the postman. I am getting the below errors.

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: status.ApiException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:78)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:222)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:422)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:213)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:228)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
```

Is it because of the dependency version conflicts?

Comment: That's not really enough to go on. What container are you running in? Is there more to the stack trace?